# Writing `double...` instead of `[] double`

Tags: java, arrays

```
public MonomialPolynomial(double... coeffs){
    List<IMonom> monoms = new ArrayList<IMonom>();

    for (int i = 0; i < coeffs.length; i++) {
        // zero coeffs might yaffect the degree
        if(coeffs[i] != 0)
            monoms.add(new Monom(coeffs[i], i));
    }

    super.monoms = monoms;
}
```

Why do people write `double...` and not `[] double` when they mean to array?
Is there a special meaning for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`double...` declares it a "var args" parameter -- inside your method it's **identical** to `double[]` but for the caller, it's much easier to call with *varying numbers of arguments* (hence var args) without the need to explicitly create an array:

Without var args:

```
MonomialPolynomial(double[] coeffs) { ...}
...
// explicit array creation necessary
new MonomialPolynomial(new double[] {1, 2, 3)};
```

With var args:

```
MonomialPolynomial(double... coeffs) { ...}
...
// array gets created implicitly, so less boilerplate code
new MonomialPolynomial(1, 2, 3);
```

---

Edit: One thing to watch out for with var args, **only the last argument** of a method can be a var args argument. This guarantess there's no ambiguity when calling a method, e.g.

`foo(int a, int b...)` is unambigious, because the first argument will always be assigned to `a` and anything after that will be go into of `b`.

`foo(int a..., int... b)` on the other hand is ambigious, there's no way to tell if `foo(1, 2, 3)` means `a={1} and b={2, 3}` or `a={1, 2} and b={3}`.

Comment: Yep, it's just a convenience for the caller -- I edited the code block comment, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`double...` is a varargs (variable arguments) feature. This means you can provide the constructor with an array of `double`s, or you can provide the constructor with any number of `double`s, and it is put into an array for you. (Example: `MonomialPolynomial(1.0, 5.0, 6.0)`.)

Answer (score 0):

It is the `vararg` feature, that is, all the arguments the function gets are collected into an array. In that case, an array of doubles. The feature is for hardcoded arrays and such. If `MonomialPolynomial` were to accept a `double[]`, you would have to use such oneliners:

```
MonomialPolynomial(new double[] {1, 2, 3});
```

But with variable arguments you may write a bit neater code:

```
MonomialPolynomial(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Err... is that the same as `f(double, ...)`? Is the comma optional?

Comment: You're probably confused by the automagic widening cast happening here from `int` to `double` -- in Java you can assign any "smaller" data type to a a "larger" type. So because an `int` fits nicely into a `double`, it's no problem to write new `double[]{...` and then only put `int`s in there -- they'll all get widened to doubles.

Comment: @Progo: I mean whether `(double...)` is the same as `(double, ...)` -- I wasn't sure if the OP just has an ordinary variadic function, or if there's more going on than that.

Comment: @Kerrek, oh sorry. `double,...` wouldn't make much sense in java context. The function is variadic but the arguments have to be of type `double`